Normalized Nash Equilibrium odd definition
Im confused by trying to understand the defition of a normalized Nash equilibrium in the continuous setting. Considering each player minimizing function is given by $\theta_v(x_v,x_{-v}): X\to\mathbb{R}$, it is stated as follows
A point $x^* \in X$ is a normalized Nash equilibrium iff $\sup_{y \in X}\psi(x^*,y) \leq 0$. In which $\psi(x,y)$ is the Nikaido-Isoda function given by
$\psi(x,y) = \sum_v \theta(x_{v},x_{-v})- \theta(y_{v},x_{-v})$
I don't understand how $\sup_{y \in X}\psi(x^*,y) < 0$ could be possible if $x^* \in X$.
